# How to add types to module federation component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to set the type of a custom component, which is exposed via the Webpack module federation. The expose and the usage working fine but Typescript is complaining about the type of the component.
I have a "frame"-module which exposes a `Sidebar` component. This is used inside my "App"-module.

```json
            new ModuleFederationPlugin({
                name: 'app',
                filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
                remotes: {
                    frame: 'frame@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
                },
```

```js
   import Sidebar from 'frame/Sidebar'  //<- Cannot find module 'frame/Sidebar' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I've tried several things to declare the type inside the "App"-module. I've created a `@types` folder inside my `src` folder. Inside this I've created two more folders "frame/Sidebar" and inside there an `index.d.ts`

```js
import { VFC } from 'react'

declare module 'frame/Sidebar' {
    const Sidebar: VFC
    export default Sidebar
}
```

I've tried to move the file to different levels inside the `@types` folder, renamed it to `frame.d.ts`, tried a different declaration

```js
declare module 'frame' {

    const Sidebar: VFC
    export { Sidebar }
}
```

But nothings works. I don't know, if typescript even recognizes my declaration, but the documentation states: "By default all visible ”@types” packages are included in your compilation.". So somehow my declaration is wrong.
Can anybody help me to correctly declare the type for this component?

Answer (score 3):

I've found my problem. It seems like `imports` should be listed inside the `declare module` and not before. `Types` on the other hand can be defined outside. So this is the correct notation inside the `src/@types/frame/Sidebar/index.d.ts` file:

```js
type SidebarProps = {
 ...
}

declare module 'frame/Sidebar' {

    import { VFC } from 'react'

    const Sidebar: VFC<SidebarProps>
    export default Sidebar
}
```